# Google INVISIBLE reCaptcha + jQuery validate() issue

Tags: jquery, validation, recaptcha, invisible

I have implemented new [Google's INVISIBLE reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) on several sites successfully, however, it conflicts with jQuery validate(), in such a way that the js validation is no longer executed on button/form submit, and reCaptcha instantly kicks-in. If user forgets to fill-in a requried form field, it will have to wait for server response, and get back to it next time.

jQuery .validate() supports callback, but because of the fact that it is hard-coded inside an internal class of a CMS, is there a way I can modify it somehow outside (e.g. from front-end theme, on document load, when validation code is already rendered)?

Or, another idea would be to postpone captcha's callback somehow, so that validation step can get a chance to run.

Thanks!

**jQuery Validate form: (hard-coded in the core, can't be modified, unless I edit core file or extend class/clone function - not optimal)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form[name=comment_form]").validate({
        rules: {
            body: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1
            },
            authorEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        wrapper: "li",
        errorLabelContainer: "#comment_error_list",
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#comment_error_list').offset().top }, { duration: 250, easing: 'swing'});
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            $('button[type=submit], input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**reCaptcha explicit render:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var renderInvisibleReCaptcha = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; ++i) {
        var form = document.forms[i];
        var holder = form.querySelector('.invisible-recaptcha');
        if (null === holder) continue;
        (function(frm){
            var holderId = grecaptcha.render(holder, {
            'sitekey': 'my-key-here',
            'badge': 'inline',
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': function (recaptchaToken) {HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(frm);},
            'expired-callback': function(){grecaptcha.reset(holderId);}
            });
            frm.onsubmit = function (evt){evt.preventDefault();grecaptcha.execute(holderId);};
        })(form);
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to try validating the form first—and when it is verified to be valid (sans the captcha part), you invoke reCAPTCHA programatically: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks, but if I knew that, I wouldn't be asking the question :)
Looks easy, sure, but not sure how to bind result from form validation and call captcha.

Comment: It looks like all `validate()` does is add a couple of event handlers. Try clearing them with `$('.form').off('submit')` or `$('.submit-button').off('click');` perhaps. I'd post as a definitive answer, but can't set up the fiddle to check at the moment...

Comment: Not sure what is the idea, but quick test - doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @dev101 did you find a solution for this question?

Comment: No, and still don't have time to get back on this and check other "solutions".

Comment: I was able to get this to work after some trouble. One minor detail i overlooked is that your .invisible-recaptcha element has to be a div, not the button. i'm not sure why that makes such a huge difference, but it does

Comment: It looks like you may not be including the recaptch/api.jjs script properly.
I would try `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderInvisibleReCaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>`

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, I finally found the right way to integrate jquery validate with invisible reCaptcha. It's a mix of some of the proposed solutions here.

First of all, the the HTML part:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<your key here>"
    data-size="invisible" 
    data-callback="formSubmit">
</div>
```

Then, you must implement the reCaptcha callback in that way:

```
function formSubmit(response) {
    // submit the form which now includes a g-recaptcha-response input
     $("#orderform").submit();
    return true;
}
```

And finally, the tricky part is in the jquery validate's submitHandler:

```
   submitHandler: function (form) {
        if (grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
                // 2) finally sending form data
                form.submit();
        }else{
                // 1) Before sending we must validate captcha
            grecaptcha.reset();
            grecaptcha.execute();
        }           
    }
```

The sequence is as follows:

1. When user hits submit button, jquery's submitHandler is called, as
   invisible recaptcha isn't executed yet, we call grecaptcha.execute().
   It takes some seconds for google's recaptcha to validate, and when
   it's fully validated it'll call formSubmit callback (while this callback isn't called, we cannot send form data to the server!).
2. In formSubmit callback we call $('#orderform').submit to force to enter
   submitHandler again.
3. Inside submitHandler again, this time as
   grecaptcha.getResponse is not null, we can post the form data to the
   server, it will include the recaptcha hidden field, which must then
   be validated on the server side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the `div` needs a closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: I can't get this to work, this is my submithandler: $("form[name='contact']").submit(function(event){ //almost the same as in yours, except that I've added an event.preventdefault in the else } got any idea why it does not work for me? I have to press the submit twice for it to work FYI

Comment: This worked for me as a <button>, but not as a <div> which is fine for my case.  <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="" data-size="invisible" data-callback='formSubmit'>Submit</button>

Answer (score 7):

I was having the similar problem and validated the form before executing [invisible reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html) with the help of this [link](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#example) provided by Terry.

Here are the steps:

Add this div before the submit button in your form

```
 <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
      data-sitekey="your_site_key"
      data-callback="onSubmit"
      data-size="invisible"></div>
```

Update your key as well. 
After the form closure  add this method

```
<script>onload();</script>
```

Before your form add this code

```
<script>
function validate(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 if (!document.getElementById('field').value) {
   alert("You must add text to the required field");
 } else {
   grecaptcha.execute();
 }
}

function onload() {
 var element = document.getElementById('submit');
 element.onclick = validate;
}
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Do all the validations in validate method and if all the validations are successful then execute captcha.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will give it a go, however, I must use explicit render because of multiple forms. The top part with manual addition of captcha div holder will require different implementation.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need help with the multiple forms too. Also, post your solution of multiple forms.

Comment: Sorry, cannot accept this as an answer, because it does not answer the original question: 1) there are no IDs, but names; 2) use of explicit render; 3) read additional condition in question description. If you post an answer to original question, I will happily accept it, but this is the answer to something completely different I haven't asked. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Technically all we "really" want to do is Programmatically bind the challenge to a button. For example:

Add this method, which we want only to execute the invisible grecaptcha instead of "real" validation

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("iv_recapcha_valid", function(value, element) {
        return grecaptcha.execute();
    }, 'No message needed, grecaptcha excecuted');
```

Then add this rule to your existing rules

```
rules: { gRecaptchaResponse: { iv_recapcha_valid: true } }
```

add a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="gRecaptchaResponse" value="" >
```

Now, "technically" the submit button is bound to the user's click action

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to use jquery to select the form (I had been using getElementByID) and then "return true".  So instead of this:

```
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
        <script>
            function onSubmit(token) {
                document.getElementById("frm").submit();
            }
        </script>
        <button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-block btn-primary" data-sitekey="<YOUR_KEY>" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
```

use this:

```
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
        <script>
            function onSubmit(token) {
                $("#frm").submit();
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-block btn-primary" data-sitekey="<YOUR_KEY>" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue working on classic Asp.Net Core MVC template.
It was internally decorated by the Unobstrusive Validation.
After inserting Invisible recaptcha, the validation was broken.
Reading this article, I managed to make it working, using the integrated validation, without the need of specifying validation for every field (inferred by Model Class into MVC project)

HTML Page:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="gRecaptchaResponse" id="gRecaptchaResponse" value="" /> 

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div id='recaptcha' class="g-recaptcha"
                         data-sitekey="@_configuration["InvisibleRecaptcha:SiteKey"]"
                         data-callback="SubmitRegistration"
                         data-size="invisible"></div>
                    <button type="submit" id="SubmitButton" class="btn btn-primary"> Invia</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
 <script>

        function onload() {
            var element = document.getElementById('SubmitButton');
            element.onclick = validate;
        }
        onload();

        function validate(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $("#Form").validate();
            var isFormValid = $("#Form").valid();
            if (isFormValid) {
                grecaptcha.execute();
            }
        }

        function SubmitRegistration(data) {
            if ($("#gRecaptchaResponse").val() == '') {
                $("#gRecaptchaResponse").val(data);
            }
            document.getElementById("Form").submit();
        }  

    </script>
```

Hope this piece of code can help someone

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when using .NET Razor Pages, which uses jquery validation by default.  Most of the solutions above manually call into captcha.  I wanted to use the [Automatic Binding to a Button](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#automatically_bind_the_challenge_to_a_button) approach.  This would cause captcha to run first, and if we successfully got a captcha token, then I'd run jquery validation and possibly submit the form.  By default this automatic binding approach breaks the jquery validation triggers.

**Set the button up for captcha**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn primary-btn g-recaptcha h-100"
                        data-callback='onSubmit'
                        data-sitekey='@Model.CaptchaKey'
                        data-error-callback="onCaptchaError"
                        data-badge="inline"
                        data-action='submit'>
                    Submit <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </button>
```

**Handle the captcha events for success/fail**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
        //Once we get a valid Captcha code, let's verify the form's unobtrusive validation
        $("#your-form-id").validate();
        var validationResult = $("#your-form-id").valid();
        if (validationResult) {
            //If we are valid, submit!  Otherwise errors will show and we don't want to submit
            document.getElementById("your-form-id").submit();
        }
    }

    function onCaptchaError() {
        alert("We had some trouble accessing captcha resources.  Please refresh the page and try again.");
    }

</script>
```

**Extra Credit: Style the captcha badge**
Make sure you follow [Google's policies on this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-hide-the-recaptcha-badge.-what-is-allowed) though

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```